# Anonymous role cannot make contribution

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute, civimember, iats

Help wanted –
Suddenly, our donation and membership pages are stop working (the credit card fields are gone). Anonymous role cannot make contribution or sign up for membership. When an anonymous user filled out all the required screens, clicked on “review your contribution” and was given this error: Payment Method is a required field.
I am using WordPress 5.5.1, IATS and CiviCRM 5.29.1. I checked the Access Control (Permissions) in WordPress; it shows anonymous role can” Make payments or donations through your (our) website”.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Does it all work correctly for logged in users?  It sounds like a permissions issue.  Do you have any plugins/extensions that relate to permissions?  If so, can you temporarily disable those and try again?

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem with a WordPress install. In my case the *Anonymous* role of WordPress missing.

The Wordpress roles can be checked with

```
wp role list
```

I created the new role with

```
wp role create anonymous_user 'Anonymous User'
```